# Creating json having different keys and values with spray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

My requirement is creating a json like

```
"filters":{  
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"Value2",
        "key3":"Value3",
    .........
     },
```

Here the all the keys and values name are different. i.e.keys are not fixed type.Also the number of keys and values may vary at different time. How can I work on such kind of issue.

I know in case class the keys are constant only value got change. I am new to spray. I need all yours suggestions, if possible some example or sample codes. Please let me know how should I start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```scala
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

      val map = Map(
        "key1" -> "value1",
        "key2" -> "Value2",
        "key3" -> "Value3"
      )

      def jsonWithMap(map: Map[String, String]): Map[String, Map[String, String]] =
        Map("filters" -> map)

      println(s"${jsonWithMap(map).toJson}")
```

**Update**

According to comment code should look like:

```scala
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val filterFormat = jsonFormat1(FilterComponent.apply)
  }
  import MyJsonProtocol._
  def createfilterJSON(): JsValue = {
    val configMap = Map("time_start" -> "request", "time_end" -> "request", "time_type" -> "request")
    FilterComponent(configMap).toJson
  }

  println(s"$createfilterJSON")//just for debug
```

Comment: Thank you Andrzej for your response.

Comment: case class FilterComponent(filter :Map[String, String])                         object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
implicit val filterFormat = jsonFormat1(FilterComponent.apply)}                          def createfilterJSON(sc:SparkContext,queryParameter: QueryParameter):JsValue={
    val configMap = Map(
      "time_start"->"request",
      "time_end"->"request",
      "time_type"->"request"
    )
    val filterjson = FilterComponent(configMap).toJson
    return kpijson;
  } error could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type

Comment: Hi Andrzej Please check the above one proper or not. I got 2 error                 1. could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type               2.not enough arguments for method jsonFormat    . I need your suggestion please check it.

Comment: When I ran urs program i got   
Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class at jsonWithMap(map).toJson}")  . Also got 
not enough arguments for method toJson